# Get data for column

Tags: extjs, rally

I have a simple rally app that renders a basic grid. I filter by looking for "WorkProduct.AcceptedDate" between two dates, this works fine.

Where I have my issue is that I want to also return the "WorkProduct.AcceptedDate" in the data grid but this does not seem to want to work :(

So what do you think I am not taking into consideration?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Grid Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/apps/2.0rc1/sdk.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        Rally.onReady(function() {
            Ext.define('CustomApp', {
                extend: 'Rally.app.App',
                componentCls: 'app',

                launch: function() {
                    Rally.data.ModelFactory.getModel({
                        type: 'Task',
                        success: function(model) {
                            this.grid = this.add({
                                xtype: 'rallygrid',
                                model: model,
                                columnCfgs: [
                                    'FormattedID',
                                    'Name',
                                    'Owner',
                                    'Estimate',
                                    'WorkProduct',
                                    'WorkProduct.AcceptedDate',
                                    'ToDo',
                                    'c_HoursWorked'
                                ],
                                storeConfig: {
                                    filters: [
                                        {
                                            property: 'WorkProduct.AcceptedDate',
                                            operator: '>=',
                                            value: '2016-07-01T23:59:59.000Z'
                                        },
                                        {
                                            property: 'WorkProduct.AcceptedDate',
                                            operator: '<=',
                                            value: '2016-07-31T23:59:59.000Z'
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            });
                        },
                        scope: this
                    });
                }
            });

            Rally.launchApp('CustomApp', {
                name: 'Grid Example'
            });
        });
    </script>

    <style type="text/css">
    </style>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think the dot in the name might be a problem. I have not found any documentation on 'rallygrid', but if it is anythink like a grid, you can put in a configuration like so: `{ dataIndex: 'WorkProduct.AcceptedDate', renderer: function() { //renderer code`. Hard to say without more code. Could you perhaps supply a fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

You're super close to having it.  Check out the example below.

You just need to specify the AcceptedDate column in your columnCfgs and include a renderer function to correctly render out the date.

The second change required is to add AcceptedDate to the fetch in your storeConfig so we ensure that data is returned for each associated WorkProduct.

I also upgraded your app to the latest SDK version 2.1.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Grid Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/apps/2.1/sdk.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        Rally.onReady(function() {
            Ext.define('CustomApp', {
                extend: 'Rally.app.App',
                componentCls: 'app',

                launch: function() {
                    Rally.data.ModelFactory.getModel({
                        type: 'Task',
                        success: function(model) {
                            this.grid = this.add({
                                xtype: 'rallygrid',
                                model: model,
                                columnCfgs: [
                                    'FormattedID',
                                    'Name',
                                    'Owner',
                                    'Estimate',
                                    'WorkProduct',
                                    //Use object syntax for specifying a column here, including a renderer function.
                                    {
                                        text: 'Accepted Date',
                                        dataIndex: 'WorkProduct',
                                        renderer: function(value, metaData, record) {
                                            var date = record.get('WorkProduct').AcceptedDate;
                                            return Rally.util.DateTime.formatDate(date);
                                        }
                                    },
                                    'ToDo',
                                    'c_HoursWorked'
                                ],
                                storeConfig: {
                                    filters: [
                                        {
                                            property: 'WorkProduct.AcceptedDate',
                                            operator: '>=',
                                            value: '2016-07-01T23:59:59.000Z'
                                        },
                                        {
                                            property: 'WorkProduct.AcceptedDate',
                                            operator: '<=',
                                            value: '2016-07-31T23:59:59.000Z'
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    //need to fetch AcceptedDate as well
                                    fetch: ['AcceptedDate']   
                                }
                            });
                        },
                        scope: this
                    });
                }
            });

            Rally.launchApp('CustomApp', {
                name: 'Grid Example'
            });
        });
    </script>

    <style type="text/css">
    </style>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```